# Hook to add content after date in post?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

This code

```
function test($the_date) {
  return $the_date . 'after';
}

add_filter ('get_the_date' , 'test');
```

adds 'after' after the date, which is what I want. But it adds it inside the date link tag. I would like 'after' to be outside of the date code.

Any way or hook to make this possible?

Comment: This isn't possible with a hook. You would need to add the code to the theme template.

Comment: Ok, you can say this as answer, i'll select it